# Upgrade issue in wix custom installer

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I am facing the issue that if I am trying to upgrade my custom installer it popping the uninstall UI of the older version.
I actually want to uninstall the old version in silent mode. Please suggest a way to uninstall the old bundle without popping up UI. I am using WIx 3.10 version, windows 64 bit OS

Comment: You need to explain exactly how you are uninstalling the previous product because an uninstall typically shows a progress UI (if manual) or no UI at all (if a major upgrade). And what UI are you seeing? Progress bar? Full dialogs?

Comment: I am using customized UI which works in a flow of different views like installview, progressview, finishview etc. For uninstall it is uninstallview,  Finishview, which works inside a dispatcher thread. Here whenever I tried to install a new version (major upgrade)it shows the uninstallview of previously installed version. I want to make it silently uninstall the old version without popping up any view.